# Connection was forcibly closed error in servlet

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I am getting an error in my java servlet.  The servlet fills the fields of an existing pdf.  The page pulls up an alert asking "Do you want to open or save this file?"  So if I press "Open" or "Save" it works fine, and does the correct thing.  But.... if I press "Cancel", nothing pops up, and I get this error:

```
com.evermind.server.http.HttpIOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I am not sure why or where this error is coming about, but it says that the error is happening on this line:

```
stamp.close();
```

If more code snippets are needed, please let me know.  I just didnt want to paste everything in here, because I dont exactly know where it is happening.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Here is the majority of my relevant code:

```
    try {      

conn = ((DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(dSource)).getConnection();

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("....");    

rs = stmt.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    ....
}

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("....");

    rs = stmt.executeQuery();


if (rs.next()) {      
    ....
}  

if (isTempVerification) {

     final String tempFile = "TemporaryVerification.pdf";

     try {

         response.setHeader(contentDisposition, "attachment; filename=" + tempFile);
         reader = new PdfReader(this.getServletContext().getResource("/pdf/" + tempFile));
         stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, response.getOutputStream());
         form = stamp.getAcroFields();
         form.setField("date", current);
         form.setField("reply_line", replyLine);
         form.setField("first_middle_last", fmlName);
         form.setField("term_year_1", termYear + ".");
         form.setField("census_date", termCensus);
         form.setField("term_year_2", termYear + ".");

         //stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
         stamp.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
         errorFound = true;
         e.printStackTrace(System.err);
     } catch (DocumentException e) {
         errorFound = true;
         e.printStackTrace(System.err);
     }

} else {

    final String officialFile = "OfficialVerification.pdf";

    try {

        response.setHeader(contentDisposition, "attachment; filename=" + officialFile);    
        reader = new PdfReader(this.getServletContext().getResource("/pdf/" + officialFile));
        stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, response.getOutputStream());
        form = stamp.getAcroFields();
        form.setField("date", current);
        form.setField("reply_line", replyLine);
        form.setField("first_middle_last", fmlName);
        form.setField("status", studentStatus);
        form.setField("hr", hoursTaken);
        form.setField("term_year", termYear);
        form.setField("start_end_date", termStart + " - " + termEnd);

        //stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamp.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorFound = true;
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        errorFound = true;
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

}

} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
} catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
} finally {if (stmt != null) try {stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } if (rs != null) try {rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);}
   try {
    if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
      conn.close();
    }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
   } 
}
```

Comment: if you don't know where it is happening you should probably paste as much as you can. just my 2c.

Comment: @soulcheck ....question edited.

Comment: An aside: reader.close() is missing. Canceling on the user side might might make the error alright, as the transport is cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when u make the `stamp.close()` call, the output stream is also flushed. since you set the response headers before `stamp.close()`, the response headers are also written to the client. consequently, this causes the file download dialog to appear on the client. when the client clicks 'cancel', the http connection is terminated.

your servlets need to maintain the http connection throughout its execution as it will be writing output to the response output stream. if the http connection is terminated before the response has been committed, you will get the exception that you are seeing now.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your solution, though I am not sure how to implement it. So my *response.setHeader* needs to be moved out of the try-catch block?

Comment: Or should I do something at the bottom of the code like: if (errorFound) { ...do stuff...}

Comment: you can do your stuff at the catch clause.